# Spark dropping executors while reading HDFS file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm observing a behavior where spark job drops executors while reading data from HDFS. Below is the configuration for spark shell.

```
 spark-shell \
 --executor-cores 5 \
 --conf spark.shuffle.compress=true \
 --executor-memory=4g \
 --driver-memory=4g \
 --num-executors 100
```

query: `spark.sql("select * from db.table_name").count`

This particular query would spin up ~ 40,000 tasks. While execution, number of running tasks start at 500, then the no of running tasks would 
 slowly drop down to ~0(I have enough resources) and then suddenly spikes to 500(dynamic allocation is turned off). I'm trying to understand the reason for this behavior and trying to look for possible ways to avoid this. This drop and spike happens only when I'm trying to read stage, all the intermediate stages will run in parallel without such huge spikes.

I'll be happy to provide any missing information.

Comment: What kind of data are you reading from, e.g. parquet, orc,...? How big are the files/partitions you are reading? Are they rather small (kilobytes to a few megabytes)?

Comment: Data being read is in ORC format. Each file is ~128 mb and about 364 partitions(256 files each).

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that the data is read so fast that the task scheduler needs some time assigning the next read tasks to the executors which causes these spikes. However, in my experience, this behaviour is only observed, when the files are small (some megabytes max).
You could try to verify this by saving the data in larger files.

Comment: @Alex The tasks are not finishing too fast. Each task takes about 2 mins to finish. The 500 tasks would ramp down to 0 in 10 mins and spike to 500 again. It is no a fast process. I'll try with large files and see if it has same behavior.